# array index to series

Tags: arrays, indexof

I have an array of objects like this

```
0: {slot_id: 'slot_8848241006_1657877963_1657886201'}
2: {slot_id: 'slot_8848241006_1657877963_1657886978'}
4: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657877482'}
6: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657886410'}
8: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657886563'}
```

I want this to be like this

```
0: {slot_id: 'slot_8848241006_1657877963_1657886201'}
1: {slot_id: 'slot_8848241006_1657877963_1657886978'}
2: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657877482'}
3: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657886410'}
4: {slot_id: 'slot_9495414200_1657194770_1657886563'}
```

need help in how to change the index values of array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//empty array
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, , 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];

var filtered = array.filter(function (el) {
return el != null;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).